# Modeling when missingness will go away?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, missing-data, data-imputation

Are there any guidelines for how to create a model using data whose features have some missing values that will predict well when data quality improves and there is no longer missing values?

I have some intuition about how the model views missing data. I think missing values indicate a lower probability of the outcome.

For example, I want to predict an event whose outcome is determined at the end of every year. 
- My dataset for past years has some features that have some missing values. 
- My goal is to predict the next event's outcome, which is not for 8 months. 
- I know that the quality of the input data used to predict next year's outcome is much better and has no missingness. However I won't know how this high quality data relates to the outcome until after the event occurs at the end of the year.
- I have a guess about what missing values indicate in past data. I think that they tend to mean a lower probability of the outcome, although not as much as if it takes on the lowest possible value of the features.